# What is the macOS alternative to namespaces(7) in Linux or jails in FreeBSD?

Tags: c++, c, macos, security, isolation

When I was using Linux I used to use Linux namespaces:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html

Also on FreeBSD, there are jails:

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?jail

I was wondering what the alternative was on macOS 12? I'm new to Macs so I'm just trying to learn the system and any features it might have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent feature to FreeBSD's *jails* and linux *namespaces* for **macOS** is the *App Sandbox*.

You can find relevant details in the [App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html#:%7E:text=App%20Sandbox%20is%20an%20access,Store%20must%20adopt%20App%20Sandbox.).